# How do we know that $c|a$ if $c=\gcd(a,b)$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that if $c = \gcd(a, b)$ then $c^2| ab$.

Proof: If $c = \gcd(a,b)$ then $c|a$  and $c|b$, therefore $c^2|ab$.

I do not understand how $c|a$ and $c|b$ if $c = \gcd(a,b)$

Comment: The gcd of $a,b$ is *defined* as the largest number which divides both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So without knowing that $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $b$, how can the proof be simple to you?

Comment: I liked the first version of the question better...

Comment: What is the point of this site to answer questions or criticize questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stating the solution in a very rigorous way, we can say :

Since $c=\gcd(a,b)$, so we can write that

> *there exist distinct integers $p,q$ such that $a=cp$ and $b=cq$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$.*

Hence $$ab=cp\cdot cq = c^2 \cdot pq$$

Thus we can conclude that $$c^2 | ab$$